# Correct syntax for variable in selector and using php variables with jquery?

Tags: jquery, syntax

I cannot seem to get the correct syntax for including a variable inside a selector such as `$("input[name=' + Var +']"). What i'm attempting to do is have a variable set as a php variable and with`var SomeVar = "";`then user it in a selector for a changing variable according to`$i` in a for statement.

I'm tried using quotations in various different ways, i've using `$("input[type=text]"."+var+"")` I'm running the same script for multiple products loaded from a database in one page. they each have checkboxes that add up additional options to come to a total. Also struggling with a function to have only one checkbox checked.

```
     // FOR KEEPING ATLEAST ONE CHECKBOX CHECKED //
 $(document).ready(function(){
 var checkbox3 = "<?php echo $checkbox3;?>";
 $('input[name="'+checkbox3+'"]').click(function() {
 var checkbox4 = "<?php echo $checkbox4;?>";
    $('input[name="'+checkbox4+'"]').not(this).prop('checked', false);
 });
 var checkbox3 = "<?php echo $checkbox3;?>";
 $('input[name="'+checkbox4+'"]').click(function() {
 var checkbox4 = "<?php echo $checkbox4;?>";
    $('input[name="'+checkbox3+'"]').not(this).prop('checked', false);
 });
 });
 function displayVals() {
  calcUsage();
  var mySelect1 = "<?php echo $mySelect1; ?>";
  var singleValues = $('#'+mySelect1).val();
  var pricef1 = "<?php echo $pricef1; ?>"; 
  $('#'+pricef1).val(singleValues);
  }
  // FINAL VALUE DERIVED FROM OPTIONS AND CHECKBOXES //
  var ql1 = "<?php echo $qr1; ?>";
  var $cbs = $('input[id="'+qr1+'"]');
  function calcUsage() {
  var mySelect12 = "<?php echo $mySelect1; ?>";
  var total = $('#'+mySelect12).val();
  $cbs.each(function() {
   if (this.checked)
        total = parseInt(total) + parseInt(this.value);
   });
   var usertotal1 = "<?php echo $usertotal1; ?>";
   $('#'+usertotal1).text('R ' + total +'/day');
   }
```

This script is intented to add up values together to come to a total for each product loaded on the page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's no need for you to create javascript variables to contain the string value you want to use as the selector names, just use the PHP echo directly.  I think you were confusing yourself with the quotes and double quotes.  Remember, the PHP will be parsed first, leaving the values from the PHP in the text file which ultimately contains your javascript, so look at the php blocks as their resulting string when using them as selector strings in your JS.

I have refactored your code to illustrate.  I have also simplified your checkbox selector part (although if you want a group of options available but only be able to select 1, you should really be using radio buttons).

```
function calcUsage() {
    var total = $('#<?php echo $mySelect1; ?>').val();
    $('#<?php echo $qr1; ?>').each(function() {
        if (this.checked) {
            total = parseInt(total) + parseInt(this.value);
        }
    });
    $('#<?php echo $usertotal1; ?>').text('R '+total+'/day');
}

function displayVals() {
    calcUsage();
    var singleValues = $('#<?php echo $mySelect1; ?>').val();
    $('#<?php echo $pricef1; ?>').val(singleValues);
}

$(document).ready(function(){
    $('input[type="checkbox"]').click(function(){
        $('input[type="checkbox"]').not($(this)).prop('checked', false);
    });
});
```

Comment: thanks @touson, I've read so many posts where the us of set var to php variable has been used and i guess that did add some confusion, thank you. If i ran this script externally with an `include` in the for statement it should work for every change in `$i` correct? where `$mySelect1 = "mySelect"."$i";`

Comment: Also i have multiple checkboxes and use the name to see if checked for only 2, I will also look at changing over to radio buttons. Would i  use it as follows : `$('input[name="<?php echo $checkbox3"]')`?

Comment: You forgot the closing php tags : `$('input[name="<?php echo $checkbox3;?>"]')`.  Remember, look at the php tags as their resulting string, so this example would render down to `$('input[name="checkbox3namefromphp"]')`

Comment: oh thanks i hadn't noticed i left out closing tags. This has helped me substantially. Thank you.

Comment: if you're interested I have another question posted regarding Jquery, I could really use the help the JSfiddle is https://jsfiddle.net/shiataz12/mjnqth3L/1/ if you're interested, I really just want to learn where i'm going wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Try making a little change in this line

```
$('input[name="'+checkbox4+'"]').not(this).prop('checked', false);
```

change it to:

```
$($('input[name="'+checkbox4+'"]').not(this)).prop('checked', false);
```

Comment: @jouston mentioned that the quotations were incorrect as it wouldn't read as PHP, is this not correct in this case?

Comment: @Websimpleton If you are talking about `var checkbox4 = "<?php echo $checkbox4;?>";` line of code then it's fine. It shall work. I don't find any issue with this line of code. Even, you may also change double quotes to single quote as well.

Comment: I'm referring to `$($('input[name="'+checkbox4+'"]').not(this)).prop('checked', false);` where there is `'` and `"` around `+ checkbox4 + `. can the `'` quotations be removed? And what is the purpose of a second `$` infront?

Comment: The purpose for this `$` in front is to select the DOM element which will come up from the inner code `$('input[name="'+checkbox4+'"]').not(this)`